# Script to use WebRTC for failover (load resources from peers when server busy)

Tags: web-apps, javascript, web-development, http

[WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) is a standard allowing direct browser-to-browser communication among peers.

Where can I find a JavaScript script that will allow users of my web application to securely get data from other users when my server is too busy to respond or dead?

For instance, my webapp allows 20 users to play against each other, and I would like static content (images/etc) to be retrieved from each other if my server is too busy, so that for each media my server gets 1 request instead of 20.